# Passing parameters to twisted factory to be passed to session

Tags: python, twisted

I have written a sshdaemon based on the twisted sshsimpleserver.py which works great.

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/conch/examples/

But I now want to pass a command line argument to the EchoProtocol, to change it's behaviour depending on the argument. 
How can I do this? In this case I would like to pass the 
'options.test' parameter to my protocol.

```
[...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
     parser = optparse.OptionParser()
     parser.add_option('-p', '--port', action = 'store', type = 'int', 
dest = 'port', default = 1235, help = 'server port')
     parser.add_option('-t', '--test', action = 'store', type = 
'string', dest = 'test', default = '123')
     (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

     components.registerAdapter(ExampleSession, ExampleAvatar, 
session.ISession)

     [...]

     reactor.listenTCP(options.port, ExampleFactory())
     reactor.run()
```

Since the session instance is created by the factory, I can't seem to 
be able to pass additional args to neither the session constructor nor the protocol.
I already tried to make the options name global but it is not visible in the protocol context/scope.

Btw. I moved the protocol class into it's own file and import it in the main file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create you own Factory and pass parameters to it. See an example from the [docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/core/howto/servers.html)

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint
from twisted.internet import reactor

class QOTD(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        # self.factory was set by the factory's default buildProtocol:
        self.transport.write(self.factory.quote + '\r\n')
        self.transport.loseConnection()


class QOTDFactory(Factory):

    # This will be used by the default buildProtocol to create new protocols:
    protocol = QOTD

    def __init__(self, quote=None):
        self.quote = quote or 'An apple a day keeps the doctor away'

endpoint = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8007)
endpoint.listen(QOTDFactory("configurable quote"))
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample and pointer, it was a good starting point. Unfortunately, the protocol is created in the ExampleSession, but this has access via protocol.session.conn.transport.factory.quote.

Comment: Within the openShell call we then can forward the quote to the CommandRecvLine via serverProtocol = ServerProtocol(CommandRecvLine, self, quote)